# Generate expiring URL on form submit

Tags: php, amazon-s3, form-submit

I have made a little PHP code that generates an expiring URL to files stored on my S3 account.
The way i have the code right now i believe it sets the expiry time on page load (when the PHP is processed).

I need the expiry time to start on a form submit (i'm using a form button as a download button, with the action set as the download url).

So when somebody clicks download, the link is generated and expiry time set.

I think i would need to call the link generation code from the form action="" but not sure how i would do this?

My code is below:

```
<?php
                // Grab the file url
                $file_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'file_url', true);
                // Grab just the filename with extension
                $file = basename($file_url); 

                // AWS details                  
                $accessKey = "<REMOVED>";
                $secretKey = "<REMOVED>";
                $bucket = "media.themixtapesite.com";

                // Set expiry time
                $timestamp = strtotime("+30 seconds");
                $strtosign = "GET\n\n\n$timestamp\n/$bucket/$item";

                // Generate Signature
                $signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($strtosign), $secretKey, true)));

                // Create new S3 Expiry URL
                $download_url = "http://$bucket/$file?AWSAccessKeyId=$accessKey&Expires=$timestamp&Signature=$signature";
                ?>

                <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
                <div class="download_button_div">


<?php echo '<form method="post" action="'.$download_url.'" class="download_button_div">'; ?>

<!--Download counter-->
                    <input type="hidden" name="download_counter" value="<?php (int)$download_count = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download_counter', true);
    $download_count++;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'download_counter', $download_count); ?>">
                    <button type='submit' class='download_button'>Download</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
```

As always, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a synchronous ajax request to get a new signature when they click the link (submit the form).

You will need to put this JavaScript on the form page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var form = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.download_button_div').submit(function(){
        form = $(this);
        var ival = form.children('[name=item]').val();
        $.ajax('ajax_sig.php', { type:'POST', async:false, dataType:'json', data:{'itm':ival}, success:function(data){
            form.prop('action', form.prop('action').replace(/Signature=.+$/, 'Signature='+data.sig));
        } });
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

You need to add this hidden input with the $item in the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $item; ?>" />
```

You will need to make the ajax_sig.php page.

```
<?php
// Item from ajax request
$item = $_POST['itm'];

// AWS details                  
$secretKey = "<REMOVED>";
$bucket = "media.themixtapesite.com";

// Set expiry time
$timestamp = strtotime("+30 seconds");
$strtosign = "GET\n\n\n$timestamp\n/$bucket/$item";

// Generate Signature
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($strtosign), $secretKey, true)));

// Ajax result
$result = array('itm'=>$item, 'sig'=>$signature);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help on this @drolex, but i'm afraid my knowledge of JS (and in fact PHP) could be written on the back of a playing card. I've added the JS code to the form page, and created the ajax_sig.php file in the same folder as that page too. Do i just leave the rest of my PHP as it was? I presume the JS intercepts each Form Submit and generates a new signature? so the signature that loads up on page load will be regenerated each time the form submit is clicked?

Comment: Did you add the hidden input to the form? Yes, leave the PHP as it was. The JS does intercept each form submit and the signature is regenerated. Is it not working? Any error messages? I assume your file download page is already set up to validate the signature with the expiry time.

Comment: I think I made a little mistake in the JS. I will fix it.

Comment: I updated all the code again and tested it (except for the signature validation part). Use the new code. Put your secret key back in. I don't know why you have to utf8_encode, base64_encode, urlencode, and have raw output of hash_hmac for your signature. Who wrote this code?

Comment: Thanks for the new code. I've added all the code as you've given. The links work. and if i try and view source then copy the generated URL in to the browser directly, S3 gives me a 'Request Expired' error, so it appears to be working. The code was a snippet used off the web. It is (as you've probably already guessed) to generate expiring URL's to files stored in our Amazon S3 bucket, and seemed to be the way everybody else does it.

Comment: Oh, and thank you once again for you awesome help on this @drolex! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to give a more complicated solution, but I thought of an easier way. Set the expiry time to +300 (give them 5 minutes or so to complete the form). You will check the signature on the target page. If the sig is bad then you don't give the file. If the sig is good then you check if the current time is past the expiry time. If so, then don't give the file.

Comment: Thanks @drolex - but the problem is we don't have a target 'page'.
The links generated are all to files. So, what i'm trying to do is once the link is clicked (and file download is initiated) the timer is set.

Comment: That's not a problem. You do have the target page, and it is the file download. Just set the timer when the page with the link opens. What's the difference? The only other way I can think to set the timer when they click is to set a signature and send them to a page that check the signature and then generates a new signature with the timer and automatically redirects them to the file download. However, it just doesn't make sense.